# Is NVRTC unavailable for Win32?

Tags: cuda, theano, mingw-w64, theano-cuda, nvrtc

I'm running Python27 x32 and getting this error:

```
Could not load "nvrtc64_75.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I've also tried with cuda8.

As I realized, [NVRTC docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html) list x64 as a requirement:

> NVRTC requires the following system configuration:
>   Operating System: Linux x86_64, Linux ppc64le, Linux aarch64, Windows x86_64, or Mac OS X.

(`nvrtc64_75.dll` really does have `0x8664` in IMAGE_FILE_HEADER and `0x20b` (pe32+) magic.)

I'm trying to use [libgpuarray](https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray/)'s `pygpu` with [theano](https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray/) and I've previously built it with Win32 mingw.

My understanding now is that I'll need to install an x64 version of python and start from there. I know I could use [conda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) instead and the docs in libgpuarray talk about msvc, [btw.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BTW#English) it worked with mingw so far.

**Am I interpreting this right? Is NVRTC really have no working Win32 edition?**

edit: got the same `%1 is not a valid Win32` error with conda x32 and msvc (no real surprise here).

Comment: Yes, you're interpreting that correctly.  nvrtc requires x64.

Comment: Is this an attempt at a rhetorical question? "I want to do this. I tried it and it doesn't work. I read the documentation, which explicitly says it won't work. But will it work?"

Comment: @talonmies no, I just don't want to overlook anything. I'm new to CUDA development and unaware of it's history so far, for example. I always want to give a chance that there is something in existence, such as a "community-driven" open-source alternative project, or an older version no longer advertised, that I'm unaware of. Since I found no rational reasoning given on *why* couldn't a 32-bit version be made, it's existence couldn't be categorically ruled out. In fact still cannot be, but since no such answer came out, I'm comfident that I'm not lacking anything obvious here.

Answer (score 1):

Just as [the documentation you linked indicates](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html), NVRTC requires a 64-bit environment.